# pdf from mean, mode, median

Tags: statistics, means, density-function

I have been given the mean, median and mode of a function and have to find the probability density function.

mean: $\gamma - \beta\Gamma_1$

median: $\gamma-\beta(ln2)^{1/\delta}$

mode: $\gamma-\beta(1-1/\delta)^{1/\delta}$

I am also given that 
$$\Gamma_k=\Gamma(1+k/\delta)$$
$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}dt$$
$$ -\infty<x<\gamma, \beta>0, \gamma>0 $$

Now I understand  how to calculate the mean, mode and median when given a probability density function. However I'm struggling to go backwards. I initially tried to "reverse" the process by differentiating the mean or median however I know this is skipping the substitution over the given limit.

I then looked for patterns with known distributions and realised they are from Weibull distribution however $\gamma-$. Does this mean essentially this is a typical Weibull distribution however shifted by $\gamma$ and therefore the pdf will be $\gamma-Weibull pdf"$

Comment: Edited: 'median', not 'medium'

Answer (score 1):

Given just the mean, median, mode and maximum, I would expect there to be an infinite number of possible distributions. But you seem to be correct that the *obvious* one is related to the Weibull distribution

What you are saying is that $W$ is a Weibull random variable with distribution scale parameter $\beta$ and shape parameter $\delta$ then one possibility is that the random variable you are looking could be $X=\gamma - W$

This Weibull distribution would have density $$f_W(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\delta}{\beta}\left(\frac{x}{\beta}\right)^{\delta-1}e^{-(x/\beta)^\delta} & x\geq0\\
0 & x<0\end{cases}$$

so if $X=\gamma - W$ then $X$ would have density $$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\delta}{\beta}\left(\frac{\gamma-x}{\beta}\right)^{\delta-1}e^{-((\gamma-x)/\beta)^\delta} & x \leq \gamma\\
0 & x>\gamma\end{cases}$$